# What is the proper way to order by a condition that depends on the current time?

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

I need to order records and put "hot" (promoted) records on top. A record is "hot" if its `hot_expires_at` column is not null and in the future. Currently I have this straightforward solution:

```
ORDER BY
  IF( hot_expires_at IS NOT NULL AND hot_expires_at > NOW(),
      hot_expires_at, from_unixtime(0)) DESC, 
  created_at DESC
```

This, however requires a filesort, and had gotten incredibly slow over time now that I have hundreds of thousands of records. (Only a small fraction of these are "hot", if that helps.)

I know I can run an additional job that calculates a `rank` field every few minutes - that would be close enough to real time. But this seems like a brute force solution.

I can also split the query into two ("hot" and "not"), and add external logic that combines the results, but that is also pretty crude and error prone.

I'm looking for the proper way to do this in MySQL and with just MySQL's facilities.

Comment: Create a calculated field (ie, Hot) with 1 or 0 as the values (Hot or Not).  Then you can `ORDER BY Hot DESC, CreatedAt DESC`

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem in a slightly different way than you currently are.  First, I would do away with the notion of having a timestamp field `hot_expires_at` which is `NULL` for old records, but not `NULL` for "hot" records.  Instead, I would change the name to `expires_at` and I would make sure that *every* record has such a field.  The clean thing about this design is that it frees you from having to store state for whether a record be hot or not.  Instead, the timestamp itself contains all the information you need to determine the label.

For the purpose of reporting, you can `SELECT` out whether or not a given record be "hot" by simply checking whether it expires at some point in the future.  So the following type of query should do the job:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN expires_at > NOW() THEN "hot" ELSE "not" END AS is_hot
FROM your_table
ORDER BY expires_at DESC, created_at DESC
```

Comment: Should not it be ORDER BY **is_hot**, expires_at DESC, created_at DESC?

Comment: @StanislavL The label "hot" is completely related to the age of the post.  So the new hotter posts will appear first just ordering by `expires_at` descending.

Answer (score 0):

When you use function NOW() it returns a value every time for evaluation of each record. As you mentioned you have hundreds of thousands of records thus their evaluation takes much time. I think you must fix the value used for IF statement in a way such as using a variable initialized by NOW() before start of query or using SYSDATE() function.

"In addition, the SET TIMESTAMP statement affects the value returned by NOW() but not by SYSDATE(). This means that timestamp settings in the binary log have no effect on invocations of SYSDATE(). Setting the timestamp to a nonzero value causes each subsequent invocation of NOW() to return that value. Setting the timestamp to zero cancels this effect so that NOW() once again returns the current date and time."